My svg animation isn't responding properly to js transformations (translation)
I coded this animation with an svg text that's supposed to move like this: first the text "Times New Roman" enters from the right side of the screen, right after that "ce" reaches it from the right, bouncing on the last word, then it all scales down and centers itself in the middle of the page. Now this works okay on my 16" laptop when it's full screen, but any change in viewport dimensions makes it all wonky. Almost all of the movements I put in js using the unit vw or vh, but when I switch to % the letters move weird and go on top of each other. Idk how to fix it :(


<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Titolo responsive</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <style>
        body {
      display: grid;
      background-color: #Faf5ed;
      height: 100%;
      place-items: center;  
      overflow: visible;
    }
    
    svg {
      overflow: visible !important;
      width: 100vw;
      transform: scale(1.9);
      animation: salire 0.5s linear forwards;
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }
    
    .centered-div {
      position: absolute;
    left:55.6%;
      top: 52% !important;
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    overflow: visible;
    }

    .st0 {
      stroke-dasharray: 613;
      stroke-dashoffset: 613;
      animation: disegno 0.35s linear forwards;
      animation-direction: reverse;
      animation-delay: 3500ms;
    fill: none;
    stroke: #f48b93;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    }
    
    @keyframes disegno {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 613;
      }
    }
    
    .scribble {
      transform: scale(0.6);
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <div class="centered-div" style="padding-bottom: 5%">
    <svg
      id="Layer_1"
      x="0px"
      y="0px"
      height="50%" 
      viewBox="0 0 3431.66 307.47" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
      style="enable-background: new 0 0 3431.66 307.47"
      xml:space="preserve"
    >
      <g id="Times_New_Roman">
        <path class="st1"
          d="M218.24,29.37l2.92,61.8h-7.38c-1.43-10.88-3.37-18.66-5.83-23.32c-4.02-7.51-9.36-13.05-16.03-16.62
                c-6.67-3.56-15.45-5.34-26.33-5.34h-37.12v201.33c0,16.2,1.75,26.3,5.25,30.32c4.92,5.44,12.5,8.16,22.74,8.16h9.13v7.19H53.83
                v-7.19h9.33c11.14,0,19.04-3.37,23.71-10.11c2.85-4.14,4.28-13.6,4.28-28.37V45.89H59.47c-12.31,0-21.06,0.91-26.24,2.72
                c-6.74,2.46-12.5,7.19-17.3,14.19c-4.79,7-7.65,16.45-8.55,28.37H0l3.11-61.8H218.24z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M292.91,109.63v143.03c0,11.14,0.81,18.56,2.43,22.25c1.62,3.69,4.01,6.45,7.19,8.26c3.17,1.82,8.97,2.72,17.39,2.72v7
                h-86.48v-7c8.68,0,14.51-0.84,17.49-2.53c2.98-1.68,5.34-4.47,7.09-8.36s2.62-11.33,2.62-22.35v-68.6c0-19.3-0.58-31.8-1.75-37.51
                c-0.91-4.15-2.33-7.03-4.28-8.65c-1.94-1.62-4.6-2.43-7.97-2.43c-3.63,0-8.03,0.97-13.21,2.92l-2.72-7l53.64-21.77H292.91z
                M276.78,16.54c5.44,0,10.07,1.91,13.9,5.73c3.82,3.82,5.73,8.45,5.73,13.9s-1.91,10.11-5.73,13.99c-3.82,3.89-8.45,5.83-13.9,5.83
                s-10.11-1.94-13.99-5.83s-5.83-8.55-5.83-13.99s1.91-10.07,5.73-13.9C266.51,18.46,271.21,16.54,276.78,16.54z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M396.93,147.53c12.95-12.95,20.6-20.41,22.93-22.35c5.83-4.92,12.11-8.75,18.85-11.47c6.73-2.72,13.41-4.08,20.02-4.08
                c11.14,0,20.73,3.24,28.76,9.72c8.03,6.48,13.41,15.87,16.13,28.18c13.34-15.55,24.61-25.75,33.81-30.61
                c9.2-4.86,18.66-7.29,28.37-7.29c9.46,0,17.85,2.43,25.17,7.29c7.32,4.86,13.12,12.8,17.39,23.81c2.85,7.52,4.28,19.31,4.28,35.37
                v76.57c0,11.14,0.84,18.79,2.53,22.93c1.29,2.85,3.69,5.28,7.19,7.29c3.5,2.01,9.2,3.01,17.1,3.01v7h-87.84v-7h3.69
                c7.64,0,13.6-1.49,17.88-4.47c2.98-2.07,5.12-5.38,6.41-9.91c0.52-2.2,0.78-8.48,0.78-18.85v-76.57c0-14.51-1.75-24.74-5.25-30.71
                c-5.05-8.29-13.15-12.44-24.29-12.44c-6.87,0-13.77,1.72-20.7,5.15c-6.93,3.43-15.32,9.81-25.17,19.14l-0.39,2.14l0.39,8.36v84.92
                c0,12.18,0.68,19.76,2.04,22.74c1.36,2.98,3.92,5.47,7.68,7.48c3.76,2.01,10.17,3.01,19.24,3.01v7h-89.98v-7
                c9.84,0,16.61-1.17,20.31-3.5c3.69-2.33,6.25-5.83,7.68-10.49c0.65-2.2,0.97-8.61,0.97-19.24v-76.57c0-14.51-2.14-24.94-6.41-31.29
                c-5.7-8.29-13.67-12.44-23.9-12.44c-7,0-13.93,1.88-20.79,5.64c-10.76,5.7-19.04,12.12-24.88,19.24v95.42
                c0,11.66,0.81,19.24,2.43,22.74c1.62,3.5,4.01,6.12,7.19,7.87c3.17,1.75,9.62,2.62,19.34,2.62v7h-88.03v-7
                c8.16,0,13.86-0.88,17.1-2.62c3.24-1.75,5.7-4.53,7.38-8.36c1.68-3.82,2.53-11.24,2.53-22.25v-68.02c0-19.56-0.58-32.19-1.75-37.9
                c-0.91-4.28-2.33-7.22-4.28-8.84c-1.94-1.62-4.6-2.43-7.97-2.43c-3.63,0-7.97,0.97-13.02,2.92l-2.92-7l53.64-21.77h8.36V147.53z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M685.56,181.92c-0.13,26.43,6.28,47.16,19.24,62.19c12.95,15.03,28.18,22.54,45.67,22.54c11.66,0,21.8-3.21,30.41-9.62
                c8.61-6.41,15.84-17.39,21.67-32.94l6.02,3.89c-2.72,17.75-10.62,33.91-23.71,48.49c-13.09,14.58-29.48,21.86-49.17,21.86
                c-21.38,0-39.68-8.32-54.9-24.97c-15.22-16.65-22.83-39.03-22.83-67.14c0-30.44,7.8-54.19,23.42-71.22
                c15.61-17.03,35.21-25.56,58.79-25.56c19.95,0,36.34,6.58,49.17,19.73c12.83,13.15,19.24,30.74,19.24,52.76H685.56z M685.56,170.65
                h82.4c-0.65-11.4-2.01-19.43-4.08-24.1c-3.24-7.25-8.07-12.95-14.48-17.1c-6.41-4.15-13.12-6.22-20.11-6.22
                c-10.75,0-20.38,4.18-28.86,12.53C691.94,144.12,686.99,155.75,685.56,170.65z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M949.32,109.63v60.63h-6.41c-4.92-19.04-11.24-32-18.95-38.87c-7.71-6.87-17.52-10.3-29.44-10.3
                c-9.07,0-16.39,2.4-21.96,7.19c-5.57,4.79-8.36,10.11-8.36,15.94c0,7.26,2.07,13.48,6.22,18.66c4.01,5.31,12.18,10.95,24.49,16.91
                l28.37,13.8c26.3,12.83,39.45,29.73,39.45,50.72c0,16.2-6.12,29.25-18.36,39.16c-12.24,9.91-25.94,14.87-41.1,14.87
                c-10.88,0-23.32-1.94-37.31-5.83c-4.28-1.29-7.77-1.94-10.49-1.94c-2.98,0-5.31,1.69-7,5.05h-6.41v-63.55h6.41
                c3.63,18.14,10.56,31.81,20.79,41c10.23,9.2,21.7,13.8,34.4,13.8c8.94,0,16.23-2.62,21.86-7.87c5.64-5.25,8.45-11.56,8.45-18.95
                c0-8.94-3.14-16.45-9.42-22.54c-6.29-6.09-18.82-13.8-37.6-23.13c-18.79-9.33-31.09-17.75-36.92-25.26
                c-5.83-7.38-8.75-16.71-8.75-27.98c0-14.64,5.02-26.88,15.06-36.73c10.04-9.84,23.03-14.77,38.96-14.77c7,0,15.48,1.49,25.46,4.47
                c6.61,1.94,11.01,2.92,13.21,2.92c2.07,0,3.69-0.45,4.86-1.36c1.17-0.9,2.53-2.92,4.08-6.02H949.32z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M1074.96,29.37h71.52l161.1,197.64V75.04c0-16.19-1.82-26.3-5.44-30.32c-4.79-5.44-12.37-8.16-22.74-8.16h-9.13v-7.19
                h91.73v7.19h-9.33c-11.14,0-19.04,3.37-23.71,10.11c-2.85,4.15-4.28,13.6-4.28,28.37v222.13h-7L1143.95,84.95v162.27
                c0,16.2,1.75,26.3,5.25,30.32c4.92,5.44,12.5,8.16,22.74,8.16h9.33v7.19h-91.73v-7.19h9.13c11.27,0,19.24-3.37,23.9-10.11
                c2.85-4.14,4.28-13.6,4.28-28.37V63.96c-7.65-8.94-13.44-14.83-17.39-17.68c-3.95-2.85-9.75-5.51-17.39-7.97
                c-3.76-1.17-9.46-1.75-17.1-1.75V29.37z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M1411.98,181.92c-0.13,26.43,6.28,47.16,19.24,62.19c12.95,15.03,28.18,22.54,45.67,22.54c11.66,0,21.8-3.21,30.41-9.62
                c8.61-6.41,15.84-17.39,21.67-32.94l6.02,3.89c-2.72,17.75-10.62,33.91-23.71,48.49c-13.09,14.58-29.48,21.86-49.17,21.86
                c-21.38,0-39.68-8.32-54.9-24.97c-15.22-16.65-22.83-39.03-22.83-67.14c0-30.44,7.8-54.19,23.42-71.22
                c15.61-17.03,35.21-25.56,58.79-25.56c19.95,0,36.34,6.58,49.17,19.73c12.83,13.15,19.24,30.74,19.24,52.76H1411.98z
                M1411.98,170.65h82.4c-0.65-11.4-2.01-19.43-4.08-24.1c-3.24-7.25-8.07-12.95-14.48-17.1c-6.41-4.15-13.12-6.22-20.11-6.22
                c-10.75,0-20.38,4.18-28.86,12.53C1418.36,144.12,1413.41,155.75,1411.98,170.65z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M1550.79,114.88h74.62v7.19c-6.87,0.52-11.37,1.75-13.51,3.69c-2.14,1.94-3.21,4.73-3.21,8.36c0,4.02,1.1,8.88,3.3,14.58
                l38.09,102.42l38.28-83.37l-10.11-26.24c-3.11-7.77-7.19-13.15-12.24-16.13c-2.85-1.81-8.16-2.92-15.94-3.3v-7.19h84.73v7.19
                c-9.33,0.39-15.94,2.07-19.82,5.05c-2.59,2.07-3.89,5.38-3.89,9.91c0,2.59,0.52,5.25,1.55,7.97l40.42,102.22l37.51-98.53
                c2.59-7,3.89-12.56,3.89-16.71c0-2.46-1.26-4.66-3.79-6.61c-2.53-1.94-7.48-3.04-14.87-3.3v-7.19h56.16v7.19
                c-11.27,1.69-19.56,9.33-24.88,22.93l-59.47,153.33h-7.97l-44.5-113.69l-51.89,113.69h-7.19l-57.13-149.64
                c-3.76-9.46-7.45-15.84-11.08-19.14c-3.63-3.3-9.33-5.8-17.1-7.48V114.88z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M2104.54,292.89l-42.17-128.07c-9.85,0.13-19.95-0.84-30.32-2.92l-22.74,79.68c-2.98,10.37-4.47,19.11-4.47,26.24
                c0,5.44,1.88,9.72,5.64,12.83c2.85,2.33,10.62,4.02,23.32,5.05l-1.75,7.19h-102.03l2.14-7.19c9.59-0.39,16.06-1.36,19.43-2.92
                c5.31-2.2,9.2-5.18,11.66-8.94c4.14-6.09,8.48-16.84,13.02-32.26l46.06-159.16c3.11-10.62,4.66-18.85,4.66-24.68
                c0-5.96-2.43-11.01-7.29-15.16c-4.86-4.15-11.82-6.15-20.89-6.02l2.33-7.19h85.9c28.76,0,49.49,5.44,62.19,16.32
                c12.7,10.88,19.04,25.2,19.04,42.95c0,16.97-6.51,32.49-19.53,46.54c-13.02,14.06-30.87,22.96-53.54,26.72l25.65,77.15
                c6.22,18.92,12.44,31.22,18.66,36.92c6.22,5.7,16.26,8.94,30.12,9.72l-2.14,7.19H2104.54z M2035.36,150.83
                c8.29,1.17,15.67,1.75,22.15,1.75c22.28,0,39.9-6.19,52.86-18.56c12.95-12.37,19.43-27.76,19.43-46.15
                c0-14.38-4.05-25.39-12.15-33.04c-8.1-7.64-20.25-11.47-36.44-11.47c-4.15,0-9.07,0.52-14.77,1.55L2035.36,150.83z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M2368.3,177.84c0,19.43-5.15,38.67-15.45,57.72c-10.3,19.04-24.65,34.14-43.04,45.28c-18.4,11.14-36.28,16.71-53.64,16.71
                c-17.75,0-32.23-5.67-43.43-17c-11.21-11.34-16.81-26.01-16.81-44.02c0-19.04,5.47-38.15,16.42-57.33
                c10.95-19.17,25.58-34.33,43.92-45.47c18.33-11.14,36.05-16.71,53.15-16.71s31.19,5.64,42.27,16.91
                C2362.76,145.19,2368.3,159.84,2368.3,177.84z M2336.04,164.43c0-12.05-2.95-21.28-8.84-27.69c-5.9-6.41-13.51-9.62-22.83-9.62
                c-19.04,0-36.57,13.64-52.57,40.91c-16,27.27-24,54.38-24,81.33c0,12.31,3.11,21.8,9.33,28.47c6.22,6.67,14.06,10.01,23.51,10.01
                c18.27,0,35.4-13.57,51.4-40.71C2328.04,219.98,2336.04,192.42,2336.04,164.43z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M2471.54,117.01l-25.26,87.65c11.27-20.6,20.86-36.08,28.76-46.45c12.31-16.06,24.29-27.72,35.95-34.98
                c6.87-4.15,14.06-6.22,21.57-6.22c6.48,0,11.85,2.07,16.13,6.22c4.28,4.15,6.41,9.46,6.41,15.94c0,6.35-1.49,14.64-4.47,24.88
                l-13.8,49.36c21.12-39.51,41.13-67.24,60.05-83.18c10.49-8.81,20.86-13.21,31.09-13.21c5.96,0,10.85,2.04,14.67,6.12
                c3.82,4.08,5.73,10.4,5.73,18.95c0,7.52-1.17,15.48-3.5,23.9l-21.38,75.6c-4.66,16.46-7,25.59-7,27.4c0,1.82,0.58,3.37,1.75,4.66
                c0.78,0.91,1.81,1.36,3.11,1.36c1.29,0,3.56-1.23,6.8-3.69c7.38-5.7,14.31-13.21,20.79-22.54l6.41,4.08
                c-3.24,5.18-8.97,12.31-17.2,21.38c-8.23,9.07-15.25,15.22-21.08,18.46s-11.21,4.86-16.13,4.86c-4.54,0-8.33-1.55-11.37-4.66
                c-3.04-3.11-4.57-6.93-4.57-11.47c0-6.22,2.65-18.72,7.97-37.51l17.68-62.38c4.01-14.38,6.15-22.35,6.41-23.9
                c0.39-2.46,0.58-4.86,0.58-7.19c0-3.24-0.71-5.76-2.14-7.58c-1.55-1.81-3.3-2.72-5.25-2.72c-5.44,0-11.21,2.79-17.3,8.36
                c-17.88,16.45-34.59,39.52-50.14,69.18c-10.24,19.56-19.82,44.63-28.76,75.21h-29.34l33.23-117.57c3.63-12.7,5.44-21.18,5.44-25.46
                c0-3.5-0.71-6.09-2.14-7.77c-1.43-1.68-3.18-2.53-5.25-2.53c-4.28,0-8.81,1.55-13.6,4.66c-7.77,5.05-17.78,15.87-30.02,32.45
                c-12.24,16.59-21.74,32.45-28.47,47.61c-3.24,7.13-10.95,29.99-23.13,68.6h-28.76l35.95-125.93l4.66-16.32
                c0.91-2.46,1.36-4.28,1.36-5.44c0-2.85-1.3-5.41-3.89-7.68c-2.59-2.27-5.9-3.4-9.91-3.4c-1.69,0-6.35,0.78-13.99,2.33l-1.75-7.19
                L2471.54,117.01z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M2861.43,117.01l-37.9,131.76l-4.28,17.68c-0.39,1.69-0.58,3.11-0.58,4.28c0,2.07,0.65,3.89,1.94,5.44
                c1.04,1.17,2.33,1.75,3.89,1.75c1.68,0,3.89-1.04,6.61-3.11c5.05-3.76,11.79-11.53,20.21-23.32l6.61,4.66
                c-8.94,13.48-18.14,23.74-27.6,30.8c-9.46,7.06-18.2,10.59-26.24,10.59c-5.57,0-9.75-1.39-12.54-4.18
                c-2.79-2.79-4.18-6.83-4.18-12.15c0-6.35,1.42-14.7,4.28-25.07l4.08-14.58c-16.97,22.15-32.58,37.64-46.83,46.45
                c-10.24,6.35-20.28,9.52-30.12,9.52c-9.46,0-17.62-3.92-24.49-11.76c-6.87-7.84-10.3-18.62-10.3-32.36
                c0-20.6,6.19-42.33,18.56-65.2c12.37-22.86,28.08-41.17,47.13-54.9c14.9-10.88,28.96-16.32,42.17-16.32
                c7.9,0,14.48,2.07,19.73,6.22c5.25,4.15,9.23,11.01,11.95,20.6l7-22.15L2861.43,117.01z M2792.24,127.12
                c-8.29,0-17.1,3.89-26.43,11.66c-13.21,11.01-24.97,27.34-35.27,48.97c-10.3,21.64-15.45,41.2-15.45,58.69
                c0,8.81,2.2,15.77,6.61,20.89c4.4,5.12,9.46,7.68,15.16,7.68c14.12,0,29.47-10.43,46.06-31.29c22.15-27.72,33.23-56.16,33.23-85.31
                c0-11.01-2.14-18.98-6.41-23.9C2805.46,129.58,2799.63,127.12,2792.24,127.12z"
        />
        <path class="st1"
          d="M2963.5,117.01l-25.85,88.42c24.23-36.15,42.78-59.92,55.68-71.32c12.89-11.4,25.29-17.1,37.22-17.1
                c6.48,0,11.82,2.14,16.03,6.41c4.21,4.28,6.32,9.85,6.32,16.71c0,7.77-1.88,18.14-5.64,31.09l-23.71,81.82
                c-2.72,9.46-4.08,15.22-4.08,17.3c0,1.82,0.52,3.34,1.55,4.57c1.04,1.23,2.14,1.85,3.3,1.85c1.55,0,3.43-0.84,5.64-2.53
                c6.87-5.44,14.38-13.73,22.54-24.87l6.02,3.69c-12.05,17.23-23.45,29.54-34.2,36.92c-7.52,5.05-14.25,7.58-20.21,7.58
                c-4.79,0-8.62-1.46-11.47-4.37c-2.85-2.91-4.28-6.83-4.28-11.76c0-6.22,2.2-16.91,6.61-32.07l22.54-78.12
                c2.85-9.72,4.28-17.3,4.28-22.74c0-2.59-0.84-4.69-2.53-6.32c-1.69-1.62-3.76-2.43-6.22-2.43c-3.63,0-7.97,1.55-13.02,4.66
                c-9.59,5.83-19.56,15.45-29.93,28.86c-10.37,13.41-21.31,30.54-32.84,51.4c-6.09,11.01-11.14,23.06-15.16,36.15l-9.72,32.07h-29.15
                l35.37-121.65c4.14-14.64,6.22-23.45,6.22-26.43c0-2.85-1.14-5.34-3.4-7.48c-2.27-2.14-5.09-3.21-8.45-3.21
                c-1.55,0-4.28,0.26-8.16,0.78l-7.38,1.17l-1.17-7L2963.5,117.01z"
        />
      </g>
      <g id="ce">
        <path class="st2"
          d="M3223.47,250.86c-13.48,16.2-27.08,28.08-40.81,35.66c-13.73,7.58-28.25,11.37-43.53,11.37c-18.4,0-32.75-5.18-43.05-15.55
                c-10.3-10.36-15.45-24.29-15.45-41.78c0-19.82,5.54-39.32,16.62-58.5c11.08-19.17,25.97-34.75,44.7-46.74
                c18.72-11.98,37.08-17.98,55.09-17.98c14.12,0,24.68,2.95,31.68,8.84c7,5.9,10.49,13.12,10.49,21.67c0,8.03-2.46,14.9-7.38,20.6
                c-3.63,4.41-8.1,6.61-13.41,6.61c-4.02,0-7.35-1.29-10.01-3.89c-2.66-2.59-3.98-5.83-3.98-9.72c0-2.46,0.49-4.73,1.46-6.8
                c0.97-2.07,2.98-4.57,6.02-7.48c3.04-2.92,4.89-5.02,5.54-6.32c0.65-1.29,0.97-2.65,0.97-4.08c0-2.72-1.23-4.99-3.69-6.8
                c-3.76-2.59-9.07-3.89-15.94-3.89c-12.7,0-25.26,4.47-37.7,13.41s-23.06,21.64-31.87,38.09c-10.62,19.95-15.94,39.91-15.94,59.86
                c0,13.21,3.76,23.68,11.27,31.39c7.51,7.71,17.75,11.56,30.71,11.56c9.97,0,19.85-2.49,29.64-7.48
                c9.78-4.99,20.76-14.02,32.94-27.11L3223.47,250.86z"
        />
        <path class="st2" 
          d="M3295.81,219.96c-0.91,6.48-1.36,11.85-1.36,16.13c0,11.53,4.08,21.35,12.24,29.44c8.16,8.1,18.07,12.15,29.73,12.15
                c9.33,0,18.3-1.91,26.92-5.73c8.62-3.82,21.41-12.27,38.38-25.36l4.08,5.64c-30.71,30.45-59.99,45.67-87.84,45.67
                c-18.92,0-33.17-5.96-42.75-17.88c-9.59-11.92-14.38-25.07-14.38-39.45c0-19.3,5.96-39.06,17.88-59.27
                c11.92-20.21,26.88-35.92,44.89-47.13c18.01-11.2,36.54-16.81,55.58-16.81c13.73,0,23.9,2.79,30.51,8.36
                c6.61,5.57,9.91,12.18,9.91,19.82c0,10.75-4.28,21.05-12.83,30.9c-11.27,12.83-27.86,23.19-49.75,31.09
                C3342.52,212.84,3322.11,216.98,3295.81,219.96z M3297.17,210.44c19.17-2.2,34.79-5.96,46.83-11.27
                c15.94-7.12,27.89-15.64,35.86-25.55c7.97-9.91,11.95-19.34,11.95-28.28c0-5.44-1.72-9.84-5.15-13.21
                c-3.43-3.37-8.33-5.05-14.67-5.05c-13.21,0-27.24,7.03-42.07,21.09C3315.08,162.21,3304.17,182.97,3297.17,210.44z"
        />
      </g> 
    </svg>
</div>
    <div class="reveal"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.5/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-7eHRwcbYkK4d9g/6tD/mhkf++eoTHwpNM9woBxtPUBWm67zeAfFC+HrdoE2GanKeocly/VxeLvIqwvCdk7qScg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script>

    const tl = gsap.timeline({default: {ease: 'power4.out', duration: 0.7}})

    gsap.set('g', { 
        autoAlpha:1
    })

    tl

        .to('#Times_New_Roman .st1', {  //spostamento times new roman verso sx
            x: '-100vw',
            duration: 1,
            delay: .5,
            ease: "circ.inOut"
        })

        .to('#ce .st2', { //spostamento ce verso sx
            x: "-100vw",
            duration: .3,
            delay: .1,
        })

        .to('g', { //spinta di ce su times new roman
            x: '-3vh',
            duration: 0.05,
            ease: 'elastic.out'
        })

        .to('g', { //recoil
            x: '1.5vh',
            duration: .1,
            ease: 'sine.in'
        })

        .to('#ce .st2', { //ce torna al posto giusto
                x: -2047,
                ease: 'power2.out',
                duration: 0.1
        })
    
        tl
        .to('svg', { //rimpicciolisce e centra tutto il titolo
            scale: 0.28,
            duration: .7,
            delay: .35,
            xPercent:-40, yPercent:0, 
        })
    </script>


    <div class="scribble">
    <svg
    version="1.1"
    id="scribble"
    x="0px"
    y="0px"
    vviewBox="0 0 224 23"
    style="enable-background: new 0 0 224 23"
    xml:space="preserve"
    >
    
    <path
      class="st0"
      d="M1.74,4.95c24.49,1.93,60.17,2.37,104.88,2.94c67.94,0.86,114.19-4.56,115.81-4.89
      c1.56-0.32-35.11,6.86-80.2,10.24C73.23,18.4,25.97,15.55,24.6,15.5c-3.07-0.11,58.45,7.51,120.82,3.64
      c29.35-1.82,54.55-1.18,71.9-3.75"
    />
    </svg>
    
    </div> 
    </body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




Can you write your code in StackOverflow Snippet syntax With the [<>] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.
